# Celeryd - send an email on log level error and above

Tags: python, django, logging, celery, django-celery

We have django configured to send us emails on any *error* or above which is triggered.  This is done using the standard LOGGING [configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) in Django.  I want this same behavior in celery.  I have it working to send me emails on Exceptions (`[CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS][2]`), but I want an email on any *defined* level - coincidentally *error* and above.

For example in any django files we can do this.

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.error("Oh No!")
```

And voilà it will send us an email assuming the following is setup in settings.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s",
            'datefmt': "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'include_html': True,
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['logfile', 'mail_admins'],
            'level': os.environ.get('DEBUG_LEVEL', 'ERROR'),
        },
    }
}
```

And for clarity I am calling celeryd like so.

```
../bin/python manage.py celeryd --settings=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE \
    --broker=amqp://RABBITMQ_USER:RABBITMQ_PASSWORD@localhost:5672/axis \
    --beat --events --pidfile=/home/var/celeryd.pid \
    --logfile=/home/logs/celeryd.log \
    --loglevel=WARNING > /dev/null 2>&1
```

And the necessary celery related settings.

```
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = True
CELERY_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 2
CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 60 * 60 * 2    # Kill anything longer than 2 hours
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 60 * 60 * 2
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = True
CELERY_MAX_PREPARING = 600
```

And finally a basic test case which I feel should send two emails.  One for the error and the other for the exception..

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

import celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.utils.serialization import UnpickleableExceptionWrapper
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

log = get_task_logger(__name__)

@periodic_task(run_every=datetime.timedelta(minutes=5))
def noise_test(**kwargs):
    log.info("Info NOISE TEST")
    log.warning("Warning NOISE TEST")
    log.error("Error NOISE TEST")

    try:
        User.objects.get(id=9999999)
    except Exception as err:
        from celery import current_app
        err.args = list(err.args) + ["Crap"]
        raise UnpickleableExceptionWrapper(
            err.__class__.__module__, err.__class__.__name__, err.args)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm looking for ways to improve this and gain a deeper level of understanding ([@asksol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5577/asksol)) but here is what I came up with.

This snippet can be placed in any `*.tasks.py` folder as it's global and will get picked up.

```
from celery.signals import after_setup_task_logger
def setup_logging(**kwargs):
    """
      Handler names is a list of handlers from your settings.py you want to 
      attach to this
    """

    handler_names = ['mail_admins']

    import logging.config
    from django.conf import settings
    logging.config.dictConfig(settings.LOGGING)

    logger = kwargs.get('logger')

    handlers = [x for x in logging.root.handlers if x.name in handler_names]
    for handler in handlers:
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        logger.setLevel(handler.level)
        logger.propagate = False

after_setup_task_logger.connect(setup_logging)
```

And let the email flow!!

Couple Notes:

- `mail_admins` corresponds to the `settings.LOGGING.handlers` which has the magic `django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler` class bound to it.
- Make sure that you disable `DEBUG` as email won't fly if `DEBUG = True`
- Make sure that you set `CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = not DEBUG`
- Make sure that your caller sets the logging level to something <= the level you want to capture.
- What is REALLY cool is then in the example above you want to accurately record the exception do this.

Try this..

```
@celery.task()
def dummy_test(**kwargs):

    log = dummy_test.get_logger()
    if settings.DEBUG:
        log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    log.debug("Debug DUMMY TEST")
    log.info("Info DUMMY TEST")
    log.warning("Warning DUMMY TEST")
    log.error("Error DUMMY TEST")
    log.critical("Critical DUMMY TEST")

    try:
        User.objects.get(id=9999999)
    except Exception as err:
        log.exception(err)
        raise
```

Now the exception will get sent in a nice email.  And each message gets printed..